# Not able to see background through png in css

Tags: html, css, vue.js, ionic-framework

I have background gradient color that looks like this:

[image: background gradient image]

When adding an image with transparency (a PNG) on top of this background, instead of the background color showing through, it's showing a black background instead:

[image: PNGs overlaid onto background, but transparent area is black instead of background color]

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <IonPage>
    <ion-content :fullscreen="true" id="start" class="background">
      <div id="product_background">
        <Topbar />
        
        <div class="container">
          <ion-text color="" class="top-left">
            <h1>ARTICS PRO</h1>
          </ion-text>
          
          <ion-text color="" class="top-left2">
            <p>Steelseries</p>
          </ion-text>
          
          <ion-text color="" class="bottom-right">
            <p>ARTICS 7</p>
          </ion-text>
          
          <ion-text color="" class="bottom-right2">
            <p>Steelseries</p>
          </ion-text>
          
          <img :src="require('@/assets/headset_mockup.png')" style="height:105vw;width:100vw" />
        </div>
        
        <div slot="bottom" style="">
          <h1>Fixed Content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </IonPage>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonContent, IonPage,IonText  } from '@ionic/vue';
import Topbar from '../Resources/Topbar.vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default  {
  name: 'Index',
  components: {IonContent, IonPage, Topbar,IonText },
  setup() {

    return {
      router: useRouter(),
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
ion-content.background{

    --background: url('../../assets/product_background.png') 0 0/100% 92% no-repeat;

    }
 #product_background{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 20px;
 }
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14px;
  right: 16px;
}
.bottom-right2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 16px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 8px;
}
.top-left2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 6px;
}
</style>
```

What could be the reason for this? Is there anything wrong with the image or the code?

Comment: Can you share your png image? I can take a look at it

Comment: its size is more than 2mb cant upload here

Comment: I have updated the answer please have look at it

Comment: Try to add 
`background-color: transparent`
in ion-content.background

or i think you can add transparent as the first parameter in the background, like this:
`--background: transparent url('../../assets/product_background.png') 0 0/100% 92% no-repeat;`

Comment: That's a very large image size for a png, you should probably compress it.

Comment: didn't work is it because my brrowser theme is black

Comment: What kind of browser are you using?

Comment: chrome. with dark theme

Comment: Looks like you picked a theme that puts black color behind the transparent image. In that case, the problem would be not with your code and I'm afraid there's nothing that you can do in your code to change that behavior.

Comment: I think this isn;t the case becasue there are color on background. and i am using two png one is headset mockup. throughheadset mokeup i can see background other one is content background through which i can not see background